# A Program Construction in Java

Tags: java, layout, constructor, initialization

I'm having an issue with my programs construction. I can't seem to find where or why I need to put my constructor in. I can't tell if it is in there, or not. Anyway, here is the main code:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HangmanProject
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        public static void getFile() {

    getFile gf() = new getFile();
    Scanner test = gf.wordScan;      
   }     
}
```

So that's the main program but it calls this one:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class getFile 
          {  
    String wordList[] = new String[10];    // array to store all of the words
    int x = 0;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);    // to read user's input

    System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman Project!");

                                 // Create a scanner to read the secret words file
    Scanner wordScan = null;

    try {
        wordScan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("words.txt")));
        while (wordScan.hasNext()) {
            wordList[x] = wordScan.next();  
            System.out.println(wordList[x]);  
            x++;  
                                   }
        } 
    finally {
        if (wordScan != null)
        {
            wordScan.close();
        }
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- where is my constructor,
- am I using it correctly,
- should my layout be changed?

My instructor is telling me that *"I still do not see the constructor method in your class where you should be initializing the instance variables for your class. You cannot just put code inside a class."* I really don't understand what that means.

Comment: I suggest you start using an IDE which properly indents your code and braces. This is kind of a mess.

Comment: There is no constructor but more importantly your program does not compile... at all...

Comment: Use of unusable Java naming convention.

Comment: If you have compilation errors you must post them here. Teaching you to understand them is of critical importance.

Comment: "You cannot just put code inside a class"?!. So what do you want. Create a constructor.

Comment: The constructor is always exist, but it may be implicit or explicit. What constructor do you need?

Comment: @Jeffrey funny thing is, I used NetBeans, but i dont really know how to use anything advanced. Maybe there is some built in function to clean up my organization of code?

Comment: @Nick: yes there is this built in functionality. Please have a look at the help files for this. It will help make your code easier for you and us to understand and also will help your *future self* better understand what you wrote 6 months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I made a few modifications to your program. Your first big error was that you have a class called getFile, and also a method called getFile. Keep method names as method names, but class names are usually capitalized. I changed it to GetFile.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class HangmanProject{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{ //this is the first thing that runs, the main method
      GetFile gf = new GetFile();  //this will create the getFile object
      try {
         gf.getWords(); //runs the method that we make later
      }
      catch(FileNotFoundException potatoes) {   //this will print out error message if there is no words.txt
         System.out.println(potatoes.getMessage());
      }                                
    } //closes main method
}
```

OK; now onto the actual class itself.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class GetFile {        
    //Here are your variables
    private String[] wordList = new String[10];   
    private int x = 0;                             
    //good practice to have variables private;
    //Now it is time for the constructor.
    public GetFile() 
       { 
     //empty constructor; you don't need to have any instance variables declared.
       } 
    public void getWords() throws FileNotFoundException {  //the big method for doing stuff
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);    // to read user's input
        System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman Project!");
        Scanner wordScan = null;
        wordScan = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
        while (wordScan.hasNext()) { //checking if there are more words
            wordList[x] = wordScan.next();  
            System.out.println(wordList[x]);  //print them out as the array is filled
            x++;  
            }
        if (wordScan != null)
           {
           wordScan.close(); //close the file after you are finished
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!!! Lifesaver!

Comment: Btw i like the potatoes. I needed a good laugh with all these problems im having. Im almost considering keeping potatoes....

Comment: Glad to be useful, I have no clue why I did potatoes.. I must have been hungry or something.

Answer (score 2):

Constructors are special subroutines that initialize objects in Java and other OO languages. Classes will have an implicit default constructor (that does nothing and returns) if you do not declare a constructor.

Other issues with your code as mentioned in the comments to your question is that it does not compile at all. You cannot put code inside a class body that is not a field or class declaration. Code that is not class or field declarations must exist in either a constructor, method, static method, initializer, or static initializer.

Oracle's own Java tutorials are an excellent resource for beginning to learn the Java language. These tutorials can be found on Oracles website and the first tutorial (linked below as Trail: Getting Started) will help you write and understand your first Java program. For the particular problem at hand the tutorial explaining the use of Classes and Objects (also linked below) will be useful.

Once you are further along you may find that you are able to ask more specific questions about concepts you get stuck on.

[Trail: Getting Started](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html)

[Lesson: Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)

[Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

You can assume Constructor as a special method with the same name as class and no return type.

So if the class name is `HangmanProject`

the constructor should be

```
public HangmanProject(){
}
```

Second it should be inside the class of which this is a constructor...

```
class HangmanProject{
    public HangmanProject(){
    }
}
```

Lastly it can take parameters as well; and you can overload them i.e. you can have multiple constructors inside a class.

```
class HangmanProject{
    Integer attemptsLeft;
    public HangmanProject(){
        attemptsLeft = 10;
    }

    public HangmanProject(Integer attempts){
        this.attemptsLeft = attempts;
    }

}
```

also the use of constructor is to initialize the fields of the class.

For your other class just as an example...

```
public class GetFile {    //  Changed as per naming convention...

     String wordList[];
     int x;
     Scanner keyboard = null;    // to read user's input
     Scanner wordScan = null;

     public GetFile(){     // Here is the constructor
         this.wordList = new String[10];
         this.x=0;
     }

}
```

Hope this helps you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Different Java programmers can have different styles and approaches to the way they program. By using standard Java naming conventions they make their code easier to read for themselves and for other programmers. Readability of Java code is important because it means less time is spent trying to figure out what the code does, leaving more time to fix or modify it.

To illustrate the point it's worth mentioning that most software companies will have a document that outlines the naming conventions they want their programmers to follow. A new programmer who becomes familiar with those rules will be able to understand code written by a programmer who might have left the company many years before hand.

[Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: This is especially useful when seeking review from others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example where I tried to fix most of the problems how you used java :-) In future think about especially using IDE like Eclipse for programming http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and learn basics of java before trying more complicated things.

Printing "Hello world" to console is way to go at first, then move on piece by piece, make another class maybe two, create some instances of them and make them print messages also to console. Don't rush on things! Learning basics is a must with every language you encounter in future, good luck with your journey! :)

**Main.java**

```
   public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

          System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman Project!");

          // lets initialize your FileHandler class, this will call its constructor btw.
          FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler();

          // and lets call its method after that
          fileHandler.readFile();

       }     

    }
```

**FileHandler.java**

```
public class FileHandler{

   // place for your attributes belonging to full class

   // Im the constructor
   public FileHandler() {
         // you can do something here like your initializations for attributes
         System.out.println("FileHandler instance created!");
   }

   public void readFile() {
         // do your file reading here
         System.out.println("FileHandler readfile() called!");
   }
```

}